# compare page title inside if condition

Tags: business-catalyst

Im trying to include a new meta tag into my business catalyst blog. Below is my structure

Main blog
http://mywebsite.com/blog

Tags
http://mywebsite.com/blog/tags/sometag

category
http://mywebsite.com/blog/category/somecat

post
http://mywebsite.com/blog/posttitle

All of the above links have a common page title except for the post page. So based on the title, so if the title is "blog" then include the meta tag

```
 {% if module_pagetitle == 'Blog' -%}
        <p>include tag{module_pagetitle}</p>
         {% else -%}
        <p>dont include tag {module_pagetitle}</p>
       {% endif -%}
```

When i include the above code to the Overall blog layout template, the page title is always empty

I also tried

```
{tag_pagetitle}
```

It doesnt seem to be working.

Can some please let me know how can i get this condition working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign the page title to a variable using Liquid's Capture and then perform the comparison against that variable. For example,

```
{% capture titleToCompare -%}
    {module_pagetitle}
{% endcapture -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to add into the Module Layouts > overall blog layout

```
<head>  
<title>{module_pagetitle}</title>
</head>
```

That should negate the need for anything else as all /blog pages that are not posts will have a title of the name of the blog, then all posts will have the post name as the title.